# What does "\\?\" means before a path?

Tags: winapi, filesystems, format, filepath

I'm having a look at the code of [FastCopy](https://github.com/laurent22/fastcopy), where I want to add a few features.

Internally, it seems that FastCopy stores its paths with a `\\?\` before the path. eg. `\\?\c:\Program Files\Adobe`. These paths are passed on directly to Windows API functions like `DeleteFile`, `RemoveDirectory`, etc. so it seems Windows understands the format.

But what do these extra characters mean and why do FastCopy stores them that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to Long UNC paths : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29 Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The thing that's probably most relevant for FastCopy is that it allows you to work with file names more than ~256 characters long.

If memory serves, it also prevents Windows from parsing a file name looking for things like `\\server\file` to access a shared file (though you can still use `\\?\UNC\whatever`), but that's probably not what's really intended/relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Generally that means it's supporting long file names - names up to about 32K in length.

It can also be used to specify UNC paths, e.g. \\?\UNC\server\share.

Without that support Fastcopy wouldn't be able to access all files properly.

More detail at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx